# How to define the points in ST_PointFromText command based on lon lat field

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr, attribute-joins

I have a filename with the columns: lon, lat, val1, val2 etc. and I want to join it with a grid shapefile in WGS84. I  use the following command but I get an error in ST_PointFromText

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT a.*, b.* FROM '$Grid_shapefile".shp"'.$Grid_shapefile AS a LEFT JOIN '$filename".csv"'.$filename AS b ON ST_Within(ST_PointFromText('POINT('lon' 'lat')', 4326), a.geometry)" $filename"gridded.shp" $Grid_shapefile".shp"
```

I tried also this

```
  ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT a.*, b.* FROM '$Grid_shapefile".shp"'.$Grid_shapefile AS a LEFT JOIN '$filename".csv"'.$filename AS b ON ST_Within(ST_PointFromText('POINT(' || b.lon || ' ' || b.lat || ')', 4326), a.geometry)" $filename"gridded.shp" $Grid_shapefile".shp"
```

but I always get error

```
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting ')'. Occurred around :
b ON ST_Within(ST_PointFromText('POINT('lon' 'lat')', 4326), a.geometry)
```

Comment: You are passing literal strings instead of column names. Use the concatenate operator (`||`) and float-string formatting (or `ST_Point`)

Comment: @Vince could you please be more specific on how to use the ST_Point in the above code? since the concatenate operator didn't work either. thank you

Comment: I used ST_Within(ST_PointFromText('POINT(|| b.lon || || b.lat ||)', 4326), a.geometry) where b is the $filename